# How to convert SQL query to optimized Rails Active Record query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this SQL query that works properly when I run it but how do I represent it and get the same data via ActiveRecord?

```
select concat(o.code, ' - ', u.name) 
from users u join user_organizations uo on u.id = uo.user_id 
join organizations o on uo.organization_id = o.id 
where u.approved = true 
  and u.deleted_at is null 
  and o.deleted_at is null 
  and u.type = 'Banker' 
order by o.code asc;
```

I tried this

```
Banker.joins(:user_organizations => :organization)
  .where(:approved => true)
  .select("concat(organizations.code, users.name)")
  .order("organizations.code asc")
```

but it didn't work and I had expected it to work.

Comment: Well what are you expecting to be the result? Your model Banker probably will not have a attribute `concat(organizations.code, users.name)`

Comment: Can you paste the generated sql

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of things to address and open questions which make it difficult to answer properly

- How are your relations set up between `Banker` and `Organization`?
- as asked before: what are you expecting?
- do you use some gem for this soft-delete feature (`deleted_at is NULL`)? (e.g. [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia))
- can you provide the generated SQL query from your version?

I assume that your setup looks sth like this

```rubz
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

If so you should be able to do the following

```ruby
User.select("concat(organizations.code, ' - ', users.name)")
    .includes(:organizations)
    .where('users.deleted_at is not null')
    .where('organizations.deleted_at is not null')
    .where('users.type = ?', 'Banker')
    .order('organizations.code ASC')
```

In case you are using the paranoia gem mentioned above for users and organizations the `*.deleted_at is not null` query parts will be added automatically which reduces the ruby query to sth like this.

```ruby
User.select("concat(organizations.code, ' - ', users.name)")
    .includes(:organizations)
    .where('users.type = ?', 'Banker')
    .order('organizations.code ASC')
```

For the rare case you don't know about the rails guides. Here's the link to the [article about associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Scuttle](http://www.scuttle.io) may be useful for your case.